# Tablespaces not created on oracle dump file import operation

Tags: oracle, import, dump

I am trying to import a dump into Oracle 11g. I have run this command :

```
impdp david/coucou@Louis-PC directory=geismar file=EXPDP_TOP.dmp log=EXPDP_TOP.log full=y;
```

The import process is successfully launched but I get a lot of errors. Here's a subset of my logfile :
Import: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Dim. Juin 25 12:02:28 2017

```
Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
;;; Legacy Mode Active due to the following parameters:
;;; Legacy Mode Parameter: "file=EXPDP_TOP.dmp" Location: Command Line, Replaced with: "dumpfile=EXPDP_TOP.dmp"
;;; Legacy Mode Parameter: "log=EXPDP_TOP.log" Location: Command Line, Replaced with: "logfile=EXPDP_TOP.log"
Master table "DAVID"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01" successfully loaded/unloaded
Starting "DAVID"."SYS_IMPORT_FULL_01":  david/********@Louis-PC directory=geismar dumpfile=EXPDP_TOP.dmp logfile=EXPDP_TOP.log full=y; 
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/USER
ORA-39083: Object type USER failed to create with error:
ORA-00959: tablespace 'TOPADDIN' does not exist
Failing sql is:
CREATE USER "TOPADDIN" IDENTIFIED BY VALUES 'S:A86A3644C5EA64C9320A5C66457EE39C51888BBD1110001C5776E9D7A554;C4D29EC4F0EAB8DE' DEFAULT TABLESPACE "TOPADDIN" TEMPORARY TABLESPACE "TEMP"
ORA-39083: Object type USER failed to create with error:
ORA-00959: tablespace 'TOPDBA' does not exist
Failing sql is:
CREATE USER "TOPDBA" IDENTIFIED BY VALUES 'S:29F9686B7D8B5861F84CA3D5720C6C8A8CFC8C7D01374D49D77DE152C234;F3A449A6B2BF4CD0' DEFAULT TABLESPACE "TOPDBA" TEMPORARY TABLESPACE "TEMP"
ORA-39083: Object type USER failed to create with error:
ORA-00959: tablespace 'TOPERP' does not exist
Failing sql is:
CREATE USER "TOPERP" IDENTIFIED BY VALUES 'S:3EC63E08F86B4922FE5328678F5E5DDD7A23D6092D539C31492FC97F2FFB;B3B7BBDA73271B0C' DEFAULT TABLESPACE "TOPERP" TEMPORARY TABLESPACE "TEMP"
ORA-39083: Object type USER failed to create with error:
ORA-00959: tablespace 'TOPMAN_USERS' does not exist
```

It seems that the import does not include the tablespaces' definition and does not create tablespaces. 
Shouldnt the option `full=y` also import tablespace definitions ?
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Same problem please let me know the solution @David Geismar

Answer (score 0):

First you can do

```
impdp david/coucou@Louis-PC directory=geismar dumpfile=EXPDP_TOP.dmp SQLFILE=check.sql
```

to see exactly what DDL the import is going to run, by viewing check.sql.

Then test some parameters, for example:

```
INCLUDE=TABLESPACE:"IN ('TOPADDIN','TOPDBA')"
INCLUDE=SCHEMA:"IN ('TOPADDIN','TOPDBA')"
```

And possibly some remaps:

```
remap_schema=
remap_tablespace=
```